# Characters being everywhere dense in the character group

Tags: number-theory, locally-compact-groups

Let $k$ be the completion of an algebraic number field at a prime divisor $\mathfrak{p}$. We note that $k$ is locally compact. Let $k^{+}$ be the additive group of $k$ which is a locally compact commutative group.

Tate's Thesis Lemma 2.2.1 states that

> If $\xi \rightarrow \chi(\xi)$ is one non-trivial character of $k^{+}$, then for each $\eta \in k^{+}$, $\xi \rightarrow \chi(\eta\xi)$ is also a character. The correspondence $\eta \leftrightarrow \chi(\eta\xi)$ is an isomorphism, both topological and algebraic, between $k^{+}$ and its character group.

The proof of this lemma is divided up into 6 steps, one step is to show that the characters $\chi(\eta\xi)$ are everywhere dense in the character group. Tate writes

> $\chi(\eta\xi) = 1$, all $\eta \implies k^{+}\xi \neq k^{+} \implies \xi = 0$. Therefore the characters of the form $\chi(\eta\xi)$ are everywhere dense in the character group.

My question is: How does he get from showing that the $\xi = 0$ to the the result that the $\chi(\eta\xi)$ are everywhere dense?

Comment: This feels like a weak-$*$ topology thing, but this isn't linear and the topology on the character group is probably the compact-open topology, so I'm getting confused. Nice question!

Comment: Following up: I think what I said above is on the right track. If you look at Section 4.1 of [Folland's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_course_in_abstract_harmonic_analysis.html?id=0VwYZI1DypUC), he shows that the topology on $\widehat G$ coincides with the weak$*$ topology it inherits as a _subset_ of $L^\infty(G)$. I need to sort this out for my own purposes, so I'll try to summarize the argument in the morning, if no one else has done so by then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the character $\xi\rightarrow\chi(\eta\xi)$ by $\chi_\eta$. We want to show that image of the map $f_\chi:\eta\rightarrow\chi_\eta$ is dense in $\hat k$. Take a closed subgroup $H$ of $k$ and set $N_H=\lbrace \xi\in k:\chi_\eta(\xi)=1\ {\rm for\ all}\ \eta\in H\rbrace$. This is also a closed subgroup. We have the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow N_H\rightarrow k\rightarrow k/N_H\rightarrow 0$$
and the functoriality of Pontryagin duality turns this into 
$$0\rightarrow \widehat{k/N_H}\rightarrow \widehat{k}\rightarrow \widehat{N_H}\rightarrow 0$$
We have an isomorphism $\widehat{k/N_H}\simeq f_\chi(H)$ (this is basically Theorem 4.39 in Folland's "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis"). Now, setting $H=k$, we see that $N_k=\lbrace 0\rbrace$, so the short exact sequence becomes
$$0\rightarrow f_\chi(k)\rightarrow \widehat{k}\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0$$
Hence $f_\chi(k)\simeq \widehat k$. This is mildly stronger than what Tate has done at this point, but I'm not worried, since we're incorporating the topology directly in the argument.